# Condition Color Formating

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, pandas-groupby

I am trying to write my dataframe results into an excel sheet with below condition.

In the below data I need to color encode each row using C2 column data. I might have 1000 rows.
If the C2 column contains TEST1 then that row should be some random color and if it contains other values then different color. Please share your thought on this one.

C1 C2

A TEST1

B TEST1

C TEST2

D TEST4

Comment: which library are you using?

Comment: @DavidErickson I am using panda

Comment: in order to write to a different color in excel, you have to a library like `xlsxwriter`. https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/working_with_conditional_formats.html